# Javascript remoting handle Asynchronous calls

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting

This question may be simple for many, but I'm unable to understand how the asynchronous calls work. I have a page where I'm making the javascript remoting call, now how long would it take for me to get the response back?, and if I have a user waiting for the response to perform other operations how do I handle that on my page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi cartman, this question, as written, is better suited for [so]. If you can revise your question to make sense in a salesforce.com specific format (e.g. adding some Visualforce, Lightning, etc code), we might be better able to assist you.

Comment: @cartman JavaScript Remoting has a callback option,   [handleResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_configuring_request.htm) (towards the bottom). An example use would be a button click listener. One the button is clicked start the progress and in the callback perform the operation on the result and stop progress.

Answer (score 1):

Using this Salesforce documentation as an example:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_example.htm

Deconstructing the script in the page, with my own comments inline, you can see that there is a JS function defined within the `invokeAction()` function. This "callback" function is executed when `invokeAction()` is finished processing your request at SFDC and that callback function has access to a couple parameters that are populated by `invokeAction()` to provide you details about the asynchronous request you made.

The amount of time it takes for the request to be made and the "callback" function to be executed is dependent on a variety of factors.

To inform your user of what's happening in the background, you could do something simple like show them a spinner right before you call `invokeAction()` and then within the "callback" function you could hide that spinner you displayed on screen earlier instructing them to wait...

```
function getRemoteAccount() {

        // get some user input from the page to be passed as a parameter
        var accountName = document.getElementById('acctSearch').value;

        // execute the remoting call and 
        // provide parameters to the invokeAction function    
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(

            '{!$RemoteAction.AccountRemoter.getAccount}', // the controller method

            accountName, // the user input captured above

            function(result, event){ // the function to execute when invokeAction finishes

                if (event.status) { // what to do in case of success

                    // Get DOM IDs for HTML and Visualforce elements like this
                    document.getElementById('remoteAcctId').innerHTML = result.Id
                    document.getElementById(
                        "{!$Component.block.blockSection.secondItem.acctNumEmployees}"
                        ).innerHTML = result.NumberOfEmployees;


                } else if (event.type === 'exception') { // what to do on exception

                    document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = 
                        event.message + "<br/>\n<pre>" + event.where + "</pre>";

                } else { // what to do in all other cases

                    document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = event.message;
                }
            }, 
            {escape: true}
        );
    }
```

Comment: Mark, Thanks for the reply. If I have to use the spinner, why can't I use action function and rerender. What makes Remoting unique?